# On the difference between pointer and array notation when used with free()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

And, welcome back to another fabulous episode of 'Puny Mortals Asking <strike>(Potentially)</strike> Dumb Questions'.

I wrote a solution to [K&R's exercise 1-16](http://www.eng.uerj.br/~fariasol/disciplinas/LABPROG/C_language/Kernighan_and_Ritchie/solved-exercises/solved-exercises.html/krx116.html) that uses dynamic memory allocation. As part of checking my work, I ran my code through Valgrind. Valgrind reported some memory leaks, though I had a 1:1 malloc:free ratio (which is perplexing).  After much fiddling and reading of the [GNU c lib manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/) *and* the [Valgrind user manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html), I eventually came to SO. None of the posts that I read really solved my problem, until I noticed some solutions to other unrelated problems that used a notation that may be expressed as the following equivalence:

`*(dbl_ptr + i) == dbl_ptr[i]`

Where `dbl_ptr` is of type `char**` and `i` is of type `int`.

In my own, original code, I had been attempting to `free()` a double pointer in the following manner:

```
for( i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i ) {
   free( (dbl_ptr + i) );     //Valgrind complains about a leak right here
}

free( dbl_ptr );
```

But when I recompile the program with these lines instead:

```
for( i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i ) {
    free( dbl_ptr[i] );    //No more Valgrind complaints
}

free( dbl_ptr );
```

The program is then reported as being memory safe. Why?

Help me to understand, merciful and benevolent StackOverlords!

**CODA:**

I recommend reading templatetypedef's answer to this post if you want a solid understanding of what happened here. I don't believe I can write a better explanation of what was going wrong within my own code. It turns out that my error was a combination of misunderstandings about how `free()` interprets arguments, as well as a fundamental ignorance of the semantics behind the array syntax in C.

Fast and dirty: `dbl_ptr[i]` implicitly dereferences `dbl_ptr + i`.

Comment: `dbl_ptr + i` means `&dbl_ptr[i]`. Similarly, `dbl_ptr[i]` means `*(dbl_ptr + i)`. They are not at all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `free`, the argument should be a pointer to the front of the block of memory you want to deallocate.

So let's suppose you have an array of `double*`s. That array looks like this:

```
  dbl_ptr ---> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ] ... [ k ]
                 |    |    |         |
                 v    v    v         v
                arr  arr  arr       arr
```

Now, suppose you call

```
free(dbl_ptr + i);
```

Graphically, `dbl_ptr + i` points here (let's pick `i = 1`)

```
  dbl_ptr + i --------+
                      |
                      v
  dbl_ptr ---> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ] ... [ k ]
                 |    |    |         |
                 v    v    v         v
                arr  arr  arr       arr
```

Therefore, `free` interprets this call as if you want to deallocate something from the middle of the block of memory allocated to `dbl_ptr`, rather than the block of memory pointed at by `dbl_ptr[i]`. That's a problem, because you can't call `free` with a pointer to the middle of a block of memory.

On the other hand, calling

```
free(*(dbl_ptr + i));
```

or

```
free(dbl_ptr[i]);
```

then you're actually saying to deallocate the memory pointed at by the `i`th element of the array pointed at by `dbl_ptr`, which is what you want.

Comment: This is clearest and most concise explanation I have seen regarding `free()` and its use with multiple indirection. Many thanks, StackOverlord!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot dereference operator in

```
free( (dbl_ptr + i) );
```

It should be

```
free( *(dbl_ptr + i) );
```

Answer (score 1):

`free` deallocates the memory pointed to by the pointer argument.  In the correct case, `free(dbl_ptr[i])`, you look up a pointer from within the array, and then free the memory that it points at.  In the incorrect case, `free( (dbl_ptr + i))`, the pointer passed to it is actually a pointer to a location within the array, a pointer to the pointer to the memory you want to free.

For an easy way to view the difference, consider the i=0 case.  the correct verison is `free(dbl_ptr[0])`.  The incorrect version is `free(dbl_ptr+0)`, which is the same as `free(dbl_ptr)`.